# How to execute a .pm file on web page

Tags: perl

I was given two .pm files that I need to trace... problem is I haven't encountered one before and I don't know how I can run it on web page for tracing.

Do I just need to upload those .pm files on my web server, go to url pointing to its location?

I'm clueless.

Comment: Voting to close: *not a real question* because the question is *vague, overly broad*. See the [Stack Overflow site FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask): »Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.« — My advice: [Learn the language.](http://learn.perl.org) Modules and how to use them is the topic that learners encounter at the threshold at about going from a beginner to an intermediate Perl programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .pm file is just a Perl module. There are quite a few interfaces that can be used to run Perl code on a webserver (including PSGI/Plack, FastCGI, mod_perl and CGI). The specifics of how you use the modules will depend on how they are designed to interface with the server. The files you have might not even be intended to be used directly.

Comment: Thanks! That was the terminology I was looking for... you made my googling easier... appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are trying to acieve you may have to create a perl-script using these pm files. You cant directly acess them using a webbrowser because these filea are more like libraries than like scripts you can run.